# Sending an error or success message only after all files have been processed

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm trying to send a success or error message in blueimp only once all the files are processed ... otherwise, the first file will send a success message and if another file has an error it will trigger the error as well.

Here is my code:

```
// Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
jQuery('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: url, 
    done: function (e, data) {
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON( data.jqXHR.responseText );
        var error = response.files[0].error;

        if(error) {
            jQuery('#error').show();
            jQuery('#error').append('<p><strong>Error given:</strong> '+error+'</p>');
        } else {
            jQuery('#success').show();  
        }
    },
});
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking for help on github Sebastian Tschan, creator of blueimp jQuery-File-Upload, suggested that I try using the `fileuploadstop` method instead of `singleFileUploads` ... However, none of the blueimp `stop` methods have a `data` parameter, Here's how I was able to overcome this issue (thanks to a developer friend for his help):

**Javascript:**

```
// Using the Basic Plus UI version of the plugin ...

// Global variables
var status = new Array(), // Create a new array
    successAll = true; // Used to check for successful upload

// After you've initialized the jQuery File Upload widget:
jQuery('#fileupload') // Replace with your form id
    .bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
        // Append the file response data to the global array, in my case "status"   
        status.push( jQuery.parseJSON(data.jqXHR.responseText) );
    })
    .bind('fileuploadstop', function (e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < status.length; i++) {
            var error = status[i].files[0].error;

            if(error) {
                jQuery('#error').show();
                jQuery('#error').append('<p><em>Error given: '+error+'</em></p>');

                successAll = false; // Change success value to false if error
            }
        }   

        // If successAll is true, meaning it wasn't reset because of an error,
        // display success message.
        if (successAll) {
            jQuery('#success').show();
        }   
        status = new Array();       
    });
```

Works great! Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This script is kinda unstable. It does not work with the autoUpload set up to true, and does not work when click the "Start Upload" button from each upload. It only works from the main "Start Upload" button to upload all the files at one shut

Answer (score 2):

## SingleFileUploads option

If you want your files were uploaded on a single request, you can use the [following option](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#wiki-singlefileuploads) : `singleFileUploads:false,`

This way only 1 *done* callback will be triggered for every files.

## Stop callback

Create a global array:

```
var temp = new Array();
```

Then in your *done*, *fail*, or *always* callback you should populate your array with file's name and the success status:

```
done: function(e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function(i, f) {
        temp.push({"name": f.name, "succeed": data.textStatus})
    })
},
```

Finally you can check every succes status into the *stop* callback which is called when every file have finished:

```
stop: function(e, data) {
    $.each(temp, function(i, f) {
        console.log(f.name)
        console.log(f.succeed)
    });
    // Don't forget to empty your array to allow other downoal
    temp= new Array();
},
```

Comment: Sweet! that fixed that issue ... however, it also created one. Now my template only shows the cancel button once, on the first file. How do I fix this? If you need more info let me know.

Comment: @Designer17 It depends, how did you show these cancel buttons?

Comment: This is the `UI` for how it appears: [UI screenshot](http://imgur.com/iL4vWNJ);
here is the `template` code that I'm using: [upload template](http://pastebin.com/BZ0f7nhP).
Hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: Can you help explain this [support](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2963) that I got from blueimp?